# Rswag schema does not fail for invalid properties of object in array

Tags: json, ruby, swagger, rswag

I have the following rswag test:

```
  response '200', 'response with array of objects' do
    schema type: :array,
      items: {
        type: :object,
        properties: {
          expected_id: { type: "integer", format: "int32" },
        }
      }

      run_test!
  end
```

My API responds with JSON:

```
[
  "invalid_key": 1,
  "invalid_key": 2
]
```

In other words, an invalid response according to the schema above.

However, the test does *not* fail. This is unexpected.

On the other hand, if my API responds with an array of null values: `"[null]"` I get the response I expect:

```
 Failure/Error: test.run

 Rswag::Specs::UnexpectedResponse:
   Expected response body to match schema: The property '#/0' of type null did not match the following type: object in schema 19e6c168-1da4-58a6-93fc-a33d9d91233a
```

So my test *is* checking that there is an array of objects, but *not* checking that the properties in the nested objects are what is expected. How do I make it check the properties as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing a `required` clause in my schema:

```
schema type: :array,
  items: {
    type: :object,
    properties: {
      expected_id: { type: "integer", format: "int32" },
    }
    required: ['expected_id'] # <- this was missing
  }
```

This raises a test error if the response my endpoint generates does not include the `expected_id` key.